# Invalid Webhook Token on interaction

Tags: discord.js

[image]

I'm making a slash command bot for Discord and there is an issue with interactions. Apparently the webhook token is only valid for 15 minutes, after that I can no longer edit the message embed. This is usually not enough time for my users as the embed relies on a transaction to hit the blockchain (which these days can take about 30 minutes).

Is there a way to refresh the webhook token for my interaction so I can extend it past 15 minutes?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Unless your code is written using an image editor, it is text, and it can be copied and pasted directly into your post here, which makes it both readable and searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that Discord supports refreshing webhook tokens, however, if you are waiting for your blockchain transaction to be completed before replying, you could defer the reply until that is done. You can do this with the [MessageComponentInteraction.deferReply()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply) method.

EDIT: After further thought, I realize that this may not actually solve your problem. You might be forced to use a standard message.reply() workflow for sending this.

Comment: I'm afraid you are correct. Looks like I need to rewrite a bunch of my code. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Discord (not discord.js) expires all interaction tokens after 15 minutes. This is a Discord limitation, and you will have to bring this up to Discord to give feedback. However, there is a workaround.

This is the recommended approach if you have a lot of requests coming through. According to your JSON data, you do not need ephemeral messages, which means that you can simply send the message as a bot user.

**Note: This requires you to have the `bot` scope when users are inviting your bot.**

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Waiting for transaction to finish...")
  // ...

await interaction.reply("See below message.");
const msg = await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

// Once the transaction finishes
const updatedEmbed = embed
  .setTitle("Transaction finished!")
  // ...

await msg.edit({ embeds: [updatedEmbed] });
```

By using a bot that sends a message, you get unlimited time to edit the message, even past 30 minutes.

Another workaround if you don't have the `bot` scope on your user's servers is to manually create server webhooks (not interactions) and edit them when needed. This requires them to invite the bot with webhook permissions, though.

This approach **does not** require the `bot` scope, however, requires webhook permissions.

```js
const webhook = await interaction.channel.createWebhook("My Bot Name", {
  avatar: "" // link to your bot's avatar (optional)
});

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Waiting for transaction to finish...")
  // ...

await interaction.reply("See below message.");
const msg = webhook.send({ embeds: [embed] });

// Once the transaction finishes
const updatedEmbed = embed
  .setTitle("Transaction finished!")
  // ...

await msg.edit({ embeds: [updatedEmbed] });
```